# String sort in which each word in the string contains a number indicating its position in the result

Tags: java, sorting, comparison

I have to sort a string in which each word in the string contains a number which tells the sort position of that word in the resultant string.Numbers can be from 1 to 9.The words in the String contains only valid consecutive numbers.
Eg: "is2 this1 test4 3a"

What is the most efficient way to solve this after splitting the string using space as the splitter, how to compare and arrange it using minimum number of loops?

Comment: I have downvoted this question because it appears to be a zero-effort requirements dump.  If you can [edit] your question to show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, or to clarify *precisely* where you are having difficulty, this downvote may be retracted.

Comment: I agree with Joe.  There is an O(n) solution which only requires 1 loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private final static String testString = "is2 this1 test4 3a"; 

public static void main(String[] args){

String[] splittedString = testString.split(" ");
Map<Integer, String> map  = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
for(String position: splittedString) {
    map.put(Integer.parseInt(position.replaceAll("[^\\d.]" , "")), position) ;
}
```

Test the logic:

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet())
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
...
```

Key here is using a TreeMap (Java standard implementation of sorted Map), that hides order work.
Rest is quite obvious I suppose...hardest thing is the regex that "cleans" string taking pure number value...

Last step:

```
String[] result = map.values().toArray(new String[map.size()]);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result).replace(",",""));
```

Hope it helps!